# Why is gdb requiring root permission to debug user programs?

Tags: linux, gdb

I have been using gdb quite successfully for a while, but I recently upgraded my version of Ubuntu, and now it seems that I can only get gdb to successfully run my program if I run as root.  That is,

```
~ %  gdb -q sleep -ex 'run 60'
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Starting program: /bin/sleep 60
tcsh: Permission denied.
During startup program exited with code 1.
(gdb)
```

fails, whereas

```
~ %  sudo gdb -q sleep -ex 'run 60'
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Starting program: /bin/sleep 60
Running .tcshrc
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7adada0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

works.  One clue is that in the first case, the gdb startup doesn't run my .tcshrc file, whereas in the second case it does.

It seems that this is a simple permissions issue, which I must have fixed at one time, because in the past, I have never needed to run gdb as root.  After much googling, however, I wasn't able to find what I might have done (if I did in fact do something).   One possible fix - set [ptrace permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process) - didn't seem to work.

Is there something that needs to be done to allow gdb to run programs without root privileges?  I know in OSX, gdb has to be codesigned.  Is there something similar for Ubuntu/Linux?

Comment: I use the system command 'sleep' above to illustrate the behavior I am seeing with my own code.  So I don't think the fact that sleep is root-owned is an issue.

Comment: did you check or modify permissions of .tcshr? why does it run tcsh anyway?

Comment: I did check permissions on .tcshrc, and changed them to root - that didn't help.  And as for why gdb is running tcsh, I don't know.  This is all very mysterious to me.  I don't want to have to run gdb as root, so would really like to figure out what has changed.  The example I gave above has no problem under OSX, so the issue isn't really the permissions on the executable (it seems).

Comment: All gdb does is `execve("/bin/tcsh", ["/bin/tcsh", "-c", "exec /bin/sleep 60"])`. tcsh will try to run `/etc/csh.cshrc`, `~/.tcshrc`, and `~/.cshrc`, so something in any of those could be causing problems. I'd check for a command that tries to read or write or source a file you don't have access to.

Comment: Thanks, [Mark Plotnick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2554472/mark-plotnick).  I am not sure what the problem was, but I reinstalled tcsh, checked .tcshrc permissions, restarted and now all is good.  Didn't change anything in my .tcshrc file, so can't point to any dubious calls that may have been the problem.  Along the way, I discovered a few cool gdb features/tricks, and so all is not lost.   In any case, I'll probably stick with bash, however, since I was using is anyway (by launching bash from the command line) to get a git prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my login shell to bash and gdb no longer needs root permission to debug.   Here is the latest :

My `.gdbinit` file:

```
(bash) ~ % more .gdbinit
show environment SHELL
file /bin/echo
run 'running .gdbinit'
(bash) ~ %
```

and the results of running `gdb` :

```
(bash) ~ % gdb -q -batch
SHELL = /bin/bash
running .gdbinit
[Inferior 1 (process 3174) exited normally]
(bash) ~ %
```

I still don't understand why tcsh didn't work, though, and am curious to know.  So if anyone has a possible explanation, please comment.

Comment: I should add that I re-installed tcsh, and ran without a .tcshrc file (I moved it), the permissions denied issue is still a mystery.   It is something funny with my setup - I just wish I could figure out what tcsh is trying to run that it doesn't have permission to run (gdb being root).

Comment: Update : I re=installed tcsh (which didn't change anything), checked (again) permission on .tcshrc, restarted and Voila, all is good with tcsh and gdb.  Still no idea what happened.  But here is what I learned : (1) gdb calls the shell and (2) the SHELL variable is not set automically by simply calling 'tcsh' or 'bash' from the command line (only when the shell is started as a login shell).  So all is not lost.

Answer (score 2):

here are some ideas for debugging the gdb problem. comments aren't really feasible for such things, so I put them into an answer.

try the `-n` option to make sure no init file is loaded.

use the `echo` program instead of `sleep 60` to make debugging simpler (the SIGINT thing in your example is probably specific to the sleep program.

run `gdb -batch` and put the rest into `~/.gdbinit`:

```
file /bin/echo
run
```

add `set verbose on`.

don't forget to clean up `~/.gdbinit` when done.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but things are becoming clearer.  The tip above was very helpful.  I created the following `.gdbinit` file

```
show environment SHELL
file /bin/echo
run 'Goodbye'
```

and the results were interesting.  If `SHELL=/usr/tcsh`, I get a permissions error, i.e.

```
~ %  setenv SHELL /bin/tcsh
~ %  gdb -q -batch
SHELL = /bin/tcsh
tcsh: Permission denied.
/home/calhoun/.gdbinit:12: Error in sourced command file:
During startup program exited with code 1.
```

Unsetting the shell variable works :

```
~ %  unsetenv SHELL
~ %  gdb -q -batch
Environment variable "SHELL" not defined.
Goodbye
[Inferior 1 (process 6992) exited normally]
```

In this case, `run` uses `/bin/sh` to expand the argument list.  Setting `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash` will use those shells to expand the argument list, e.g.

```
~ %  setenv SHELL /bin/bash
~ %  gdb -q -batch
SHELL = /bin/bash

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
Goodbye
[Inferior 1 (process 7280) exited normally]
```

Oddly, the "no loadable sections' error only happens when the shell variable is explicitly set.  Another mystery.

Why `/bin/tcsh` doesn't work is still baffling.  In my case, the permissions on `/bin/tcsh` are

```
~ %  ls -lh /bin/tcsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 14  2011 /bin/tcsh -> /usr/bin/tcsh
~ %  ls -lh /usr/bin/tcsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 382K Oct 14  2011 /usr/bin/tcsh
```

The problem could also be something in my `.tcshrc` file that is causing the shell to crash in this non-interactive mode.

Comment: I'd guess the latter is true: the permission denied error is from something that tcsh tries to execute and not from execution of tcsh itself. should be simple to find out but why bother?

Comment: Or, that tcsh is trying to do something that gdb isn't giving it permission to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your program has executable privileges.

```
ls -l .
-rw-r--r-- 1 opt opt 30010 Aug 16 16:13 test
```

Something like 'test' maybe caused that when you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I specified **Linux** in the launch.json file, via the LaunchCompleteCommand...

MS has 3 different ways to specify the CPU... Windows, Linux or OSx

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

```
    "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
      "linux": {
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
      },
```

In my launch.json file, this LaunchCompleteCommand section was pasted in after the setupCommands section.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before, and files from /usr/bin/gdb* didn't have execution permissions. This happened after I have installed peda, pwndbg and gef.

**# chmod +x /usr/bin/gdb-***

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the reason was that someone had set the sticky bit in the gdb executable:

```
cruiz> ls -l /usr/bin/gdb

-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 4190760 2010-05-05 07:55 /usr/bin/gdb*
```

I changed it (`chmod 755  /usr/bin/gdb`) and now it works.

Before:

```
cruiz> gdb
...

(gdb) shell

csh: Permission denied.
```

After the change:

```
cruiz> gdb

(gdb) shell

cruiz>
```